# How Can i prevent My APK Extract In Phonegap

Tags: cordova

i have problem with the file protection for my Application In Phone gap. i am tried to set user permission apk properties In Windows 7. is it right Method ?  i Don't know about any encryption method. Please Help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is Basically Not any Trick for Complete Avoidance of your Problem. But you can Still Use Proguard and Make your Code more obfuscation.

If you have the option of including shared libraries then also you can use and integrate it for making it harder to reverse engineered.

you can View HERE for More ways for Preventing your APK file

Hope it will Help.

Comment: @deepak link is missing